# Bitcoin Core frozen trying to sync and/or connecting to peers

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I downloaded Bitcoin Core directly to my laptop and sent BTC to what i believe is my wallet. The BTC is no longer in my senders wallet and I do not see it in my bitcoin core wallet. It was working slowly but now it is frozen at 12 percent.

Comment: so i checked my adress on a block explorer and the BTC is there..so that is a good thing...i finlly got it to 60 % synced but it keeps running out of storge so I have to delete 5-15 gb and then it once again runs out of space ive been doing this for 3 days now. Is there a way to have it save to an external SSD? i cloned my os but it doesnt seem to want to boot and I dont want to delete or format the disk in fear that it will lose my BTC

Comment: ok so now it says replaying blocks...press q to shutdown and it stays at 0%

Answer (score 1):

Your wallet will need to sync to the network before your funds will be shown as available. This is because the ‘sync’ process involves your node verifying the history of transactions, so the transaction you received cannot be verified until all other preceding transactions have been verified first.

If you think it has frozen during the sync, I’d suggest turning the debugger on, and then looking at the `debug.log` file for clues on what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Check your address on a [block explorer](https://www.blockchain.com/explorer), your funds are like there. As the other answer mentioned, these won't be visible until your wallet syncs.

If you're in a hurry, you can download the blockchain via torrent, then move it to your data folder.

Alternatively, you can import your private keys into a light wallet, which will show your balance immediately

Comment: could i get a link to the download of the blockchain via torrent...and...or....instructions on how to find and import my private keys...tia

Comment: Sure, see [private key export/import instructions](https://www.bitcoin.com/guides/how-to-import-and-export-bitcoin-private-keys)